# UIViewController background Image

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, background-image

How do I set the background image of my UIViewController? What is the code to do it? Right now I have

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];
```

but I don't want a pattern. I want it to fill the screen properly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you could use:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blah.png"]];

[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
[backgroundImage release];
```

[Apple HD image Guide](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/prerelease/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH10)

Comment: The iPhone 4 is 960-by-640-pixel resolution at 326 ppi according to Apple's website. When I make an image this large, it is way too big for a background when i try putting it on my phone using that code. How do I make it fit? I'm trying to make a high resolution background for one of my applications.

Comment: ahh. I would try reading up on the point to pixel conversion (there is a guideline to this somewhere). I personally am not exactly sure how it works, but you would just have to adjust the UIImageViews frame perhaps? I personally have never used  the HD resolution for iPhone4.

Comment: What do you mean "points to pixel" conversion? Would you mind helping me find some guide on this?

Comment: added a link in my answer to the apple guide on supporting HD images.

Comment: This code will cause a memory leak. You'll need to add `[backgroundImage release];` as the last line of code here.

Comment: @Fulvio: +1: true true..fixed :)

Comment: The last line of code fixed an issue for me. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 7):

self.view.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"].CGImage;

Reason: each view is backed by a CALayer class. According to documentation on CALayer:

```
contents
An object that provides the contents of the layer. Animatable.


@property(retain) id contents

Discussion
A layer can set this property to a CGImageRef to display the image as its contents. The default value is nil.
```

And yes, this property is animatable. This means that nice transitions based on CoreAnimation can be done on this layer.
Note: be careful if you support multiple orientations.

Answer (score 4):

A swift solution for this...

```
let backgroundImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "backgroundImage"))
backgroundImageView.frame = view.frame
backgroundImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
view.addSubview(backgroundImageView)
view.sendSubviewToBack(backgroundImageView)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for Swift 3.0

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "home02.png")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Jesse Naugher's code: UIView (or UIViewController, for that matter), holds no built-in way of using an image for background. What you have to do is to use a UIImageView, which is a UIView subclass specifically for displaying images, and add that to the back of your view hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you. I understand. Do you have any wisdom on the matter that I posted as a comment to Jesse Naugher's code?